# Why does my React component display incorrect data when filtering by values controlled by useState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of objects that I'd like to pass to a map function which passes each object as props to a component to be rendered.

I have a menu and clicking each item calls setActiveItem() updating activeItem which is being managed by useState hook.

I'm trying to filter the list of objects based on this activeItem value. I've created a base case trying to replicate the problem but my base case works flawlessly though it'll at least clarify what I'm trying to do so here it is:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const [ALL, NUMBER, LETTER] = ['All', 'Number', 'Letter'];
const data = [
  {
    tags: [ALL, NUMBER],
    value: '1'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, LETTER],
    value: 'a'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, NUMBER],
    value: '2'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, LETTER],
    value: 'b'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, NUMBER],
    value: '3'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, LETTER],
    value: 'c'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, NUMBER],
    value: '4'
  },
  {
    tags: [ALL, LETTER],
    value: 'd'
  }
];

const renderData = (allValues, filterTag) => {
  let filteredList = allValues.filter(val => {
    return val['tags'].includes(filterTag);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredList.map(object_ => {
        return object_.value;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const BaseCase = props => {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(ALL);
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu inverted stackable fluid widths={4}>
        <Menu.Item
          name={ALL}
          active={activeItem === ALL}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name={NUMBER}
          active={activeItem === NUMBER}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name={LETTER}
          active={activeItem === LETTER}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
      </Menu>
      <div>{renderData(data, activeItem)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BaseCase;
```

Clicking number only shows numbers and everything else works as expected. Now for my component that isn't working. I have my data in a separate file like so:

```
import { BASH, DATA_SCIENCE, WEB_DEV, ALL } from '../constants';
const data = [
  {
    tags: [ALL],
    title: 'Concussion App for Athletes',
     .
     .
     .
  },
  {
    tags: [DATA_SCIENCE, ALL],
    title: 'Deep Learning: Exploring Car Value with an ANN',
    ...
  },
  .
  .
  .
];
export default data;
```

Here's my component. There's some commented out code that I tried but that also gave incorrect components being displayed.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ProjectCardContainer from '../../containers/ProjectCardContainer';
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { ALL, BASH, DATA_SCIENCE, WEB_DEV } from './constants';
import data from './project_data';
import './Projects.scss';

const styles = {
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-around'
  },
  columns: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    marginTop: '11px'
  }
};

const renderColumn = (projectList, filterTag) => {
  let projects = projectList.filter(proj => {
    return proj['tags'].includes(filterTag);
  });

  return (
    <div style={styles.columns}>
      {projects.map(project => {
        return <ProjectCardContainer project={project} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const Projects = () => {
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(ALL);

//   const [, updateState] = React.useState();
//   const forceUpdate = useCallback(() => updateState({}), []);

//   useEffect(() => {
//     setTimeout(forceUpdate, 100);
//   }, [activeItem]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='second-nav-container'>
        <Menu inverted stackable fluid widths={4}>
          <Menu.Item
            name={ALL}
            active={activeItem === ALL}
            onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            name={WEB_DEV}
            active={activeItem === WEB_DEV}
            onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            name={DATA_SCIENCE}
            active={activeItem === DATA_SCIENCE}
            onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
          />
          <Menu.Item
            name={BASH}
            active={activeItem === BASH}
            onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
          />
        </Menu>
      </div>
      <div style={styles.container}>{renderColumn(data, activeItem)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

Basically the rendered list of components usually isn't correct except maybe when the page is refreshed and the default value from useState() is used. Selecting from the menu doesn't show the components of the correct category.

I believe the problem is that the render function is getting called before activeItem is updated  but I'm not sure how to work around that issue. I'm somewhat new to using hooks but this seems like a problem that must come up a lot.

Anyone Have any ideas how I can use a menu like this to filter data then only show specific components based on filtered data?

Comment: Just for clarification - you have a drop down menu with a list of the tags, and when you select a specific tag you want to render out all objects from `data` that have that tag?

Comment: Nevermind I see the example. 1 min

Answer (score 1):

The problem in the end was I wasn't providing a unique key while rendering lists of components. The solution is to provide a unique key like so:

```
const renderColumn = (projectList, filterTag) => {
  let projects = projectList.filter(proj => {
    return proj['tags'].includes(filterTag);
  });

  return (
    <div style={styles.columns}>
      {projects.map(project => {
        return <ProjectCardContainer key={project.title} project={project} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

In my case I know the titles will be unique so this works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we need to mess around too much with complicated state management. I updated the base case to meet your needs:

Constants.js:

```
export const [ALL, DATA_SCIENCE, WEB_DEV, BASH] = ['All', 'DATA_SCIENCE', 'WEB_DEV', 'BASH'];
```

data.js:
import {ALL, DATA_SCIENCE, WEB_DEV, BASH} from './Constants';

```
const data = [
    {
        tags: [ALL],
        title: 'Concussion App for Athletes',
      },
    {
        tags: [DATA_SCIENCE, ALL],
        title: 'Deep Learning: Exploring Car Value with an ANN',
    },
    {
        tags: [BASH, ALL],
        title: 'Bash 101'
    },
    {
        tags: [WEB_DEV, ALL],
        title: 'Web Development Book'
    },
    {
        tags: [WEB_DEV, ALL],
        title: 'Fundamentals of web design'
    }
]

export default {data};
```

BaseCase.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Menu } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import data from './data';
import {ALL, DATA_SCIENCE, WEB_DEV, BASH} from './Constants';


const renderData = (allValues, filterTag) => {

  let filteredList = Object.values(allValues.data).filter(val => {
    return val['tags'].includes(filterTag);
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {filteredList.map(object_ => {
        return <p>{object_.title}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const BaseCase = props => {

const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(ALL);

const newData = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <Menu inverted stackable fluid widths={4}>
        <Menu.Item
          name={ALL}
          active={activeItem === ALL}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name={DATA_SCIENCE}
          active={activeItem === DATA_SCIENCE}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name={WEB_DEV}
          active={activeItem === WEB_DEV}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
        <Menu.Item
          name={BASH}
          active={activeItem === BASH}
          onClick={(e, { name }) => setActiveItem(name)}
        />
      </Menu>
      <div>{renderData(newData, activeItem)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BaseCase;
```

At `return <p>{object_.title}</p>;` render out your component like `<ProjectCardContainer project={object_} />`

Comment: That's exactly what was in my question (return <ProjectCardContainer project={project} />;  what was needed was a unique key because those containers were being rendered as a list